# How to get a padded slice of a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am stuck on a little issue in the project I am currently working on.

Getting straight to the point, let's assume I have a 2-dimensional `numpy.array` - I will call it `arr`.

I need to slice `arr`, but this slice must contain some padding depending on the selected interval.

Example:

```
arr = numpy.array([
    [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
    [  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
    [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [ 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
])
```

Actually, `numpy`'s response for `arr[3:7, 3:7]` is:

```
array([[19, 20],
       [24, 25]])
```

But I need it to be padded as if `arr` were bigger than it really is.

Here is what I need as response for `arr[3:7, 3:7]`:

```
array([[19, 20,  0,  0],
       [24, 25,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

This padding should also occur in case of **negative indices**. If the requested slice is bigger than the whole image, padding **must** occur in all sides, if needed.

Another example, negative indices. This is the expected result for `arr[-2:2, -1:3]`:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0, 11, 12]])
```

Is there any native `numpy` function for this? If not, any idea of how can I implement this?

Comment: Negative indices already have a meaning in NumPy—the same one as in Python in general, where -N means "N elements back from the end". Overloading it to mean something different in some cases but not others would be a recipe for serious confusion.

Comment: Also, NumPy normally returns you views rather than copies whenever possible. But that's obviously not possible whenever there might be padding. So, this wouldn't be a good idea for indexing in general.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But well, the scope here is simply a `numpy` function or an internal method.

Comment: But meanwhile, you can always do this manually in a wrapper function: work out the padding, `stack` on a `zeros`, and slice that. Or slice them stack, which is a bit more complicated but probably more efficient. Or, if you really want, you can write a padded array class that handles `__getitem__` this way…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the first part of your question you can use a simple indexing, and you can create a `zero_like` of your array with `numpy.zeros_like` then assign the special part :

```
>>> new=numpy.zeros_like(arr)
>>> part=arr[3:7, 3:7]
>>> i,j=part.shape
>>> new[:i,:j]=part
>>> new
array([[19, 20,  0,  0,  0],
       [24, 25,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

But for the second case you can not use a negative indexing for for numpy arrays like this.**Negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end of the array** so if you are counting from `-2` actually in a 5x5 array there are **not** any row between -2 and 2 so the result would be an empty array :

```
>>> arr[-2:2]
array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Interesting answer, I'll give it a try. I know that negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end of the array, but I imagined there could a single numpy function that could ignore it. Thank you for your answer, I'll  try to change the logic to address this issue.

Comment: NB I don't think the OP wanted np.zeros_like(arr) I think they wanted np.zeros(xd * yd).reshape(xd, yd) where xd and yd are the differences in the request i.e. 4=7-4, 4=2 - -2 and 4=3 - -1 as I have attempted to do below.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
print np.lib.pad(arr[3:7,3:7], ((0, 2), (0, 2)), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0 ))



[[19 20  0  0]
 [24 25  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0]]
```

For the negative indexing:

```
print np.lib.pad(arr[ max(0,-1):3 , 0:2 ], ((1, 0), (2, 0)), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0 ))

[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  2]
 [ 0  0  6  7]
 [ 0  0 11 12]]
```

Check [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for reference

Comment: How you get `((0, 2), (0, 2))` what about the other scenarios?

Comment: @Kasra:He can handle the padding as he wants.As for negative I added something.

Comment: These can be simplified to `numpy.lib.pad(arr[3:7, 3:7], ((0, 2), (0, 2)), 'constant')` and `numpy.lib.pad(arr[:3, :2], ((1, 0), (2, 0)), 'constant')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def convert(inarr, x1, x2, y1, y2):
  xd = x2 - x1
  yd = y2 - y1
  outarr = np.zeros(xd * yd).reshape(xd, yd)
  x1fr = max(0, x1)
  x2fr = min(x2, inarr.shape[0])
  y1fr = max(0, y1)
  y2fr = min(y2, inarr.shape[1])
  x1to = max(0, xd - x2) 
  x2to = x1to + x2fr - x1fr
  y1to = max(0, yd - y2)
  y2to = y1to + y2fr - y1fr
  outarr[x1to:x2to, y1to:y2to] = inarr[x1fr:x2fr, y1fr:y2fr]
  return outarr


arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
               [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
               [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
               [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

print(convert(arr, -2, 2, -1, 3))
```

Well this works but returns

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  6.  7.  8.]]
```

for your -ve index example. You can play around to get it to do what you expect